# How to reset filter programmatically on listview for Kendo Mobile?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I have configured a listview to enable filtering. In another event, how can I reset the filter?

This is what I have:

```
  $("#listview").kendoMobileListView({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        template: $("#listview-template").text(),
        filterable: {
            field: "ProductName",
            operator: "startswith"
        }
    });
```

In another function, how can I reset the filter so the listview shows all again (in case someone typed a search)?

```
$("#listview").data("kendoMobileListView")...??
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do:

```
$("#listview").data("kendoMobileListView").dataSource.filter({});
```

Comment: Thanks I also had to do this: $('[type="search"]').val('')

Comment: I think the two statements are needed to completely simulate the filter reset. One of the statements alone does not really give the desired effect on my system.

Answer (score 1):

One-liner that will clear the input text and handle dataSource filtering by triggering the clearButton click event:

```
$("#listview").data("kendoMobileListView")._filter.clearButton.click();
```